# Windows PDF printer with no dialog

Tags: windows, pdf, printing

When printing documents in SAP Business One (our ERP) it automatically goes to default printer. If I set any printer, it goes straight to the printer. No questions. If I set 'Microsoft Print to PDF' as default printer, a dialog box is opened asking where to save the generated PDF.

I'm trying to write a program that prints a bunch of documents as PDF, so I need them to be saved somewhere without asking me where to store each one.

Is there any software that creates a new printer, and can be configure to save all PDF files in a specific folder?

*(Gratis if possible)*

Comment: Did you ever try PDFCreator? We have done a lots of automated printings with them.

Answer (score 1):

The company I work for has a printer driver that can save to PDF and dozens of other file types. It allows you to define one or more Task Printers, and configure each to save to the file format and the location of your choice. Creating a Task Printer is explained in [the LEADTOOLS ePrint documentation here](https://www.eprintdriver.com/help/v6.0/Professional-Edition/#ePrintTaskPrinterCreationWizard.htm).

If you would like to consider it, I recommend trying the free evaluation edition from [this page before buying it](https://www.eprintdriver.com/Download).
Although the evaluation displays a reminder window, there’s an option to disable it for a number of days (or the entire evaluation period), which would enable you to test the no-dialog process you’re trying to get working.

[image]

Once you conclude your testing, you can either purchase ePrint from the website, or simply un-install it if you don’t need it.